# Request to reopen question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I made edits to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139442/guides-examples-of-providing-a-software-security-plan-for-a-client-with-a-focus) to narrow the scope of the question so it does not read like a "shopping" question which is out of scope per community guidelines.

I have done a lot of work in cybersecurity and believe can provide a solid answer from past work experience in consulting with clients. Best practices already exist for what the OP is looking for, and I think the "one size fits all" approach being sought is incorrect.

**Can we vote to re-open this question?**

Comment: Seems like a good edit to me.  Hopefully others will add their reopen votes.

Comment: Workplace SE is for all kind of workplaces. What are we going to do if someone asks how to come up with a _physical_ building security plan? Are we going to provide one? We deal with issues about workplaces in general, not a specific work item. The OP should go to other sites for help.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is not related to the workplace. This is a technical question about their core business. They should be asking this question on a more technical site.

Comment: Besides, OP from that post already accepted an answer, so it seems that their query or doubt was satisfied.